# excel vba select value in row, which was selected through for each

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to cycle through a range of my worksheet `rngSAP` row by row. If the value of cell 2 in that row is equal to a String, I want to use some of the data of that row. This is what I have, but I get `type not matched` error.

```
with shtSAP
    Set rngSAP = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rowsSAP, colsSAP))
    For Each cellSAP In rngSAP.Rows
        If cellSAP(2).Value = "03" Then
            MsgBox (cellSAP(5))
        End If
    Next
end with
```

Can anyone help me out with the right code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
With shtSAP
    Set rngSAP = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rowsSAP, colsSAP))

    For Each cellSAP In rngSAP.Rows
        If Cells(cellSAP.Row, 2).Value = "03" Then
            MsgBox Cells(cellSAP.Row, 2).Value
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Complete example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim shtSAP As Worksheet
    Dim rngSAP As Range
    Dim cellSAP
    Dim rowsSAP As Long, colsSAP As Long

    Set shtSAP = ActiveSheet

    rowsSAP = 5: colsSAP = 5

    With shtSAP
        Set rngSAP = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rowsSAP, colsSAP))

        For Each cellSAP In rngSAP.Rows
            'Debug.Print Cells(cellSAP.Row, 2).Address
            If Cells(cellSAP.Row, 2).Value = "03" Then
                MsgBox Cells(cellSAP.Row, 2).Value
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

OR this perhaps?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim shtSAP As Worksheet
    Dim rngSAP As Range
    Dim cellSAP
    Dim rowsSAP As Long, colsSAP As Long

    Set shtSAP = ActiveSheet

    rowsSAP = 5: colsSAP = 5

    With shtSAP
        Set rngSAP = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rowsSAP, colsSAP))
        For Each cellSAP In rngSAP.Rows
            'Debug.Print cellSAP.Cells(, 2).Address

            If cellSAP.Cells(, 2).Address = "03" Then
                MsgBox Cells(cellSAP.Row, 2).Value
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: your first solution is, what I needed. Thanks for the hint. But I have one addition. `If cellSAP.Rows(2).Value = "03"` seems cleaner to me, than `If Cells(cellSAP.Row,2).Value = "03"` or are these two equivalent?